# How to call the form properties in vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am developing a web browser in *vb.net* (win forms - visual studio 2019) and I didn't use any of the predefined Windows Ui but only my own UI.

The problem is that while adding the tool bar to form, i used a panel and inserted a long grey rectangular image as the background for panel (customised tool bar). If you increase the form's width while debugging, the panel's width is not increasing. Any way to stretch the panel as the forms's width Increases.

**Try #1**:

```
Private Sub 
     BunifuElipse1_TargetControlResized(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
     BunifuElipse1.TargetControlResized
     Panel1.Width = Form1.Width
 End Sub
```

**Error**:

> 'Form1' cannot refer to itself through its default instance; use 'Me'
> instead.

**Try #2**:

```
Private Sub 
    BunifuElipse1_TargetControlResized(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    BunifuElipse1.TargetControlResized
    Panel1.Width = Me.Form1.Width
End Sub
```

**Error**:

> 'MeForm1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
> protection level.

NB: I use *Bunifu UI* (I dont think it makes any difference here)

Comment: It is _Me.Width_, but for your purpose just set the Panel Dock property to Top in the Designer

Comment: Thanks, i just solved my purpose, I am a newbie You know ( just 15 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Me.width
And It solved My purpose.